# Primefaces FileUpload Complete call specify method

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In Primefaces 5.1 I need File upload complete to call another method. i.e. upload button press the handFileUpload action perform then upload complete to need to call another action.

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" 
mode="advanced" update="messages" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" >
</p:fileUpload>
```

I try p:ajax event="onfileUploadComplete it not working then which event to call function when upload complete?

Answer (score 1):

`p:fileUpload` has an `oncomplete` attribute:

> **Client side** callback to execute when upload ends.
>   ([PrimeFaces 5.1 Documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_1.pdf), page 207)

You can use this in combination with `p:remoteCommand` to call a bean method from a JavaScript event (see also http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml).

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" update="messages" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" oncomplete="fileUploadCallback()" />

<p:remoteCommand name="fileUploadCallback" action="#{bean.myMethod}" />
```